# Vue2: change Images without repeating HTTP request for already loaded images

Tags: image, performance, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on a product page which has an Image gallery on the left and color selections on the right.

See the below image.
[image]

Now every time a color is selected a set of image has to be shown on the left. The way it is implemented right now is that every time the color selection is updated the store value for `SelectedImages` changes with the array of that particular color.

Now it makes sense that, whenever I switch to a new color the image is loaded. Which is happening.
But the issue I am facing is that whenever the color is changed, and the `SelectedImages` array is updated the images are loaded, no matter that they were loaded earlier. I don't want it to load again (send http) when it has already called the image once.

Also, I don't want to load all the images (4 color x 4 images = 16 Images) at once which would again be not performant.

I have created this UI using vue. It's not a vue single app, but it has vue component at some places where needed.

Code that renders Image.

```js
  <div class="desktop-gallery"
    :class = "{ 'is_loading': isLoading }"
    v-bind:style="parentStyle"
    v-show="!onlyMobile">
      <div class="gallery-item"
      v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index"
      ref="variableGallery"
      @click="handleGalleryZoom(index)"
      >
     <img :src="image"/>
      </div>
  </div>
```